# Javascript array type with defined indexes?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

With typescript, apparently it is possible to have an Array() type item where you specify the index of that array as an ID. While I always assumed this was only possible in the Object() type. Example:

```
items: String[] = []
items["someid"] = new SomeClass()
console.log(items)
```

Returns:

```
items:[someid: SomeClass]
```

Although I like this idea, is it ok to use it like this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, array can only have numerical indexes. However remember that every array is an object as well. Thus, you are assigning 'someid" as a new property to the  items object.
Equivalent of

`const items = [];
//items.length is 0
items.someid = {};
//items.length is still zero`

If you want key => value property then use a Map